# How many days fall in a set of date ranges based on a date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-range

A user inputs a date range like:

From: 01/04/2015
To:   01/12/2015

I have some periods defined like:

```
var period1 = '01/04/2015';
var period2 = '01/11/2015';
```

I would like to know how many days are:

Before Period 1

After (or equal to) Period 1 but before Period 2

After (or equal to) Period 2

I would like to work this out using javascript. I am making a calculator that works out the cost of a booking based on different date ranges.

Thank you for your help,
David

Comment: Do you mean in the current year and up-to-date?

Comment: What is the format of your dates? It could be day/month/year or month/day/year.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. It is not difficult to research date differences and you are expected to at least have tried instead of expecting others to write code for you. Not to mention that your before and after criteria are missing details

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Hello, I spent about 4 hours googling and trying to work out the code before I posted on here, I found lots of simular scripts and posts on stackoverflow but nothing that does what I need. The date format would be dd/mm/yy using jquery date picker, however I know javascript date would be mm/dd/yy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing stuff with dates, I'd highly recommend using moment.js. http://momentjs.com/  Based on what you're asking for, I'd recomment starting here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/ or http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: Without a working example this is basically a link-only answer.

Comment: You are correct.  I am not going to solve the problem for you because based on your question, you haven't tried to solve the problem yourself.  You asked for help figuring out how to do this, moment.js will help you solve this problem however you want

Comment: Apologies @TomFenech, I didn't realize that you were not the OP.  Regardless, my rationale remains the same, since OP's question is vague and shows no effort on their part to solve the problem.

Comment: No problem, I'm just not sure why you posted this as an answer - it would be better as a comment.

Comment: Since there were a few links, I wanted the space an answer offered (and it does answer the question asked to a certain extent).  Nonetheless, it's a fair point and I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Thank you @taylorc93 for the link to Moment JS it was very helpful in solving the issue I had.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to work the way you need it to. (I assumed the days before/after the periods were referring to the year that date was in).

```js
function getValues() {
  // Get the dates from the textboxes
  var period1Date = new Date($('#period1').val()); 
  var period2Date = new Date($('#period2').val());
  
  var firstDayOfYear = new Date('1/1/' + period1Date.getFullYear().toString());
  var lastDayOfYear = new Date('12/31/' + period2Date.getFullYear().toString());

  // Get days between first day of year and period 1 date
  var daysBeforePeriod1 = (firstDayOfYear - period1Date)/(1000*60*60*24);
  // Get days between last day of year and period 2 date
  var daysAfterPeriod2 = (lastDayOfYear - period2Date)/(1000*60*60*24);
  // Get days between period 1 and period 2 dates
  var daysBetween = (period1Date-period2Date)/(1000*60*60*24);
  
  // Set labels on screen
  $('#daysBefore1').text('Days Before Period 1: ' + Math.abs(daysBeforePeriod1).toString());
  $('#daysBetween').text('Days Between Periods: ' + Math.abs(daysBetween).toString());
  $('#daysAfter2').text('Days After Period 2: ' + Math.abs(daysAfterPeriod2).toString());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Period 1: <input type="text" id="period1" value="01/04/2015"/>
<br><br>
Period 2: <input type="text" id="period2" value="01/11/2015"/>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="getValues()">Get Values</button>
<br><br>
<label id="daysBefore1"></label>
<br>
<label id="daysBetween"></label>
<br>
<label id="daysAfter2"></label>
```